# Recursive matching when preceded by a given pattern

Tags: regex, recursion

Consider the following two strings:

```
a (b (c) d) e
f (g (h) i) j
```

I would like to match the content in parentheses recursively. I can do so by using the following pattern:

```
\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)
```

This will match both `(b (c) d)` and `(g (h) i)`.

Now, let's say I want to match recursively the content in parentheses only when preceded by the letter `a`. How can I do that?

Using `(?<=a\s)\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of repeating the whole pattern, you could repeat create a capturing group and repeat the first sub pattern instead:

```
(?<=a\s)(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*\))
```

- `(?<=a\s)` Assert what is on the left is a and a whitespace char
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `(?>` Atomic group

    - `[^()]` Match any char except `(` or `)` (Use `[^()]+` to make it more efficient)
    - `|` Or
    - `(?1)` Recurse the first subpattern
  - `)*` Close atomic group and repeat 0+ times
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO8Pk9/1)

When adding a capturing group, we can omit the lookbehind and match `a` and a whitespace char:

```
a\s(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2yciOH/1)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** This solution should do the trick

```
(?:a\s)(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*\))
```

tested with your own strings:

a (b (c) d) e = true

f (g (h) i) j = false

a (b (c) d (f) g) e =  true

Let me know if this works and if not why not.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This will work in this very specific case only. It will not match for example `a (b (c) d (f) g) e`. Hence the need of a recursive matching.

Comment: I see, thanks for adding the other use case. Answer has been updated.

Comment: That looks familiar with `(?1)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, yes it does but your pattern does not work in any of the use cases as above. What seems to break the pattern is the first non-capturing group (lookbehind) `(?<=a\s)`. What works is the improvement of your own pattern with the first non-capturing group `(?:a\s)` which was by the way already part of my first answer.

Comment: The question states `Now, let's say I want to match recursively the content in parentheses only when preceded by the letter a` which is about the content inside the parenthesis. You can get that with or without the lookbehind. The OP uses `(?<=a\s)` so it seems that matching a is not required. So yes, my pattern works for the cases above as you can see in the demo link solved by using `(?1)`. You also don't need the non capturing group btw.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I am not in for an argument but the statements `only preceded by the letter a` and `it seems that matching a is not required` are quite clearly cancelling each other out. Your first solution does not work since the question requires a solution that includes a recursive function only after a and your first lookbehind non-capturing group breaks all the use cases as above.

Comment: What do you mean by `Your first solution does not work `? The lookbehind does not break anything. They are not cancelling each other out, what I mean is that to get the data in parenthesis using a capturing group, you don't actually have to match `a` first. That is what the assertion does when looking behind, it is not consuming.