# Recursively matching each non-digit characters when preceded by a digit

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match each individual non-digit characters that are directly preceded by a digit. The idea is to replace `O` with `0` in numbers.

E.g.:

```
58OO
1O1O
2OOOm
FOO
O
```

The desired output is

```
5800
1010
2000m
FOO
O
```

I tried using the answer in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137272/recursive-matching-when-preceded-by-a-given-pattern) I asked but I don't manage to adapt the regex to my purpose.

Here are a few regex I tried, without success (and for good reasons): `(\d\K(?>O|(?1)))` or `\d\K(?:O|(?R))`.

Comment: Please add the code you tried in the question

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I added some examples of regex I tried. I clearly understand why they don't work but couldn't figure out a way to do what I want.

Comment: The patterns you tried are for any digit that is followed with `O` or the same pattern. You do not need recursion, you either need to repeat replacing until no match is found (see Jan's answer) or use a lookbehind checking if there are any digits and Os before a `O` (see Ryszard's answer, [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cd%2bO*%29O&i=58OO%0d%0a1O1O%0d%0a2OOOm%0d%0aFOO%0d%0aO&r=0)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to install [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```
import regex
texts = ["58OO", "1O1O", "2OOOm", "FOO", "O"]
for text in texts:
  print( regex.sub(r'(?<=\d+O*)O', '0', text) )
```

Output:

```
5800
1010
2000m
FOO
O
```

The `(?<=\d+O*)O`  expression matches `O` that has digit(s) and any amount of `O`s before.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with recursion, just use a simple while loop:

```
import re

strings = ["58OO", "1O1O", "2OOOm", "FOO", "O"]

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\d)O')

for item in strings:
    while True:
        olditem = item
        item = pattern.sub("0", item)
        if item == olditem:
            # no replacement was made
            break

    print(item)
```

This yields

```
5800
1010
2000m
FOO
O
```

Comment: Thank you for yours input. I'm aware I can do that with a loop. I should probably have mentioned it but I was trying to avoid a loop because I find it a bit of an overkill here. I have hundred thousands numbers to fix. I will have to test it but I believe it's just more efficient to do it with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

A simple sub is more than enough.

Example from the `python` interpreter:

```
>>> import re
>>> raw = '''
58OO
O1O1O
2OOOm
FOO
O
'''
>>>
>>> print(re.sub(r'(\d+)(O+)', lambda m: m.group(1) +  '0' * len(m.group(2)), raw))

5800
O1010
2000m
FOO
O
```